# What is the Bash command that presses the right arrow key?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

If I need to write a Bash script that has the effect of pressing the right arrow key, how do I write that script?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`xdotool`](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) to imitate the effect of pressing the right arrow key. You can install `xdotool` using:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Then you can run the command:

```
xdotool key Right
```

- Useful: [xdotool list of key codes](https://gitlab.com/cunidev/gestures/-/wikis/xdotool-list-of-key-codes)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute a right arrow key use:

```
echo -n $'\032'  # right arrow key
```

The characters that are shown might will depend on the terminal you use.
and

```
echo -n $'\030'  # up arrow key
echo -n $'\031'  # down arrow key
echo -n $'\034'  # left arrow key
```